# PHP not logging errors

Tags: php

I have tried two different things on my server:

1. - created a directory php in /var/log/
   - changed owner:group to www-data:www-data (apache owner)
   - changed permissions of the directory to 775
   - php.ini has error_log = "/var/log/php/php.log"
   - php.ini already had error logging set to on, and error reporting set to all
   - restarted apache
2. in the code, changed error_log('message') to error_log('message',3,path_to_logfile)

Neither results in messages in the applicable log file.

Comment: Did you try this as an owner or a normal user ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question fully. If 'this' is the steps above, it was as root. If running the code, it's via the web with a browser, so not really applicable?

Comment: check its the right php.ini file you edited. gone and edited the wrong copy on many occasions

Comment: yeah, me too, but there are are only 2 on the server, /etc/php5/apache2 and /etc/php/cli, and I edited the former.

Comment: When you type, `php -r "phpinfo();"` on your command line, or call up the phpinfo page, where does it say the logging is going?

Comment: at the moment, syslog (via the browser... via the command line it would be the cli php.ini)

Answer (score 1):

You say you created /var/log, but you're trying to write to /var/log/php. Try creating a directory called php in /var/log.

Comment: I think I said I created php IN /var/log (ie /var/log/php) :-)

Comment: But even when I just go with error_log = syslog in the php.ini file, or use error_log with value 3 and a specified file, error_log statements in php go nowhere.

Comment: Ah, yes. I misread your for bullet point. Sorry about that. I'm not sure why you wouldn't be getting any log entries. Could be some odd issue between your OS version and PHP version.